# Passing multiple parameters to multiple threads

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a loop that creates several threads as such:

```
SomeClass..

Dim someNumber As Integer = 0
Dim somethingElse As Integer = 10
Dim myThread(500) As System.Threading.Thread

For i As Integer = 0 To 500
    someNumber += 1
    somethingElse += 10

    myThread(i) = New Thread(Sub() myThreadFunction(someNumber, somethingElse))
    myThread(i).Start()
Next

For j As Integer = 0 To 500
    myThread(j).Join()
Next

Sub myThreadFunction(ByVal someNumber As Integer, ByRef somethingElse As Integer)

    DoStuff

End Sub
```

Now my problem is that sometimes I get the wrong values passed to myThreadFunction, usually the value that's supposed to be passed in the next iteration of the loop.

Am I doing something wrong, and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the lambda closing over your variables in the wrong scope.  Eric Lippert describes this problem in detail in [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

To make this work, you need to introduce a temporary variable in the proper scope:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 500
    someNumber += 1
    somethingElse += 10

    ' Make some locally scoped variables
    Dim temp1 As Integer = someNumber
    Dim temp2 As Integer = somethingElse 

    ' Use the temporaries
    myThread(i) = New Thread(Sub() myThreadFunction(temp1, temp2))
    myThread(i).Start()
Next
```

On a separate note: I would recommend also considering using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx) or the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) instead of manually creating threads.  This is, in general, a better approach for most scenarios.